# Why won't Vuforia recognize my model target in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm new to Vuforia and Unity. I downloaded a cad model for a Lego brick (2x4) and created an advanced database and full 360 view for it. I'm working through my laptop's webcam on Unity on Windows. I've been through the vuforia documentation, core samples, and YouTube tutorials, but when I hit play on Unity I can't get any sign that my real red Lego brick is being recognized. I've tried putting in a GameObject Cube as a child for the ModelTarget to test recognition. One fishy thing is that I don't see any guide views in the inspector window for the ModelTarget (see screenshot). Another fishy thing is my webcam doesn't have a unique profile (last screenshot). Are Legos too small? Any ideas would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A Lego brick is about as small as MT can cope with. Your object does not have a lot of geometry, mostly the studs, and these are likely not that prominent from far view points as the one you show in your image. If it works, and this is a big if, then tracking is going to start when you are quite close. I would first try with basic tracking disabling advanced and 360, then a guide view should appear. Please make sure that the guide view is not smaller than 30% the image, larger is better as long as your camera can focus on the object. If you get this to work then you can try with 360, but make sure that the reco ranges include close views. Please also note that 360 might not work on the full range around the object due to the object being symmetric. To work around this you can try to restrict the range to views which do not include ambiguities.

Comment: In addition to that .. lego usually has a reflective surface => even worse to track and in general Vuforia needs clear tracking reference points ... if your object is symmetric on two axis it is already confusing which orientation should be applied